# xfce4-notes not showing in Unity menu

Tags: unity, launcher, xfce

I use `xfce4-notes` and I liked it a lot. My issue, it is not showing in Unity application menu, is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

- Create the folder `$HOME/.local/share/applications` if it doesn't exist
- Copy the file `/usr/share/applications/xfce4-notes.desktop` into the folder `$HOME/.local/share/applications`
- Open the file `$HOME/.local/share/applications/xfce4-notes.desktop` in a text editor, for example gedit
- Remove the line

  ```
  OnlyShowIn=XFCE;GNOME;
  ```

  near the end of the file
- Save the file